# How to remove barcode text from Zend_Barcode

Tags: magento-1.9, orders, shipment-tracking, packing-slip

This is related to magento packing slip printing , I have added a barcode using Zend_Barcode function but when draw barcode it automatically include the barcode text just underneath the barcode image. I need to remove it , following is my code

```
<?php
$code = "barcode-text";     
$file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code), array());
$code = time().$code;
$store_image = imagepng($file,Mage::getBaseDir().DS.'barcodes'.DS."{$code}.png");
$page->drawImage($image, 300,$this->y-40,430,$this->y+10);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

agh found the solution

```
$file = Zend_Barcode::draw('code128', 'image', array('text' => $code, 'drawText' => false), array());
```

just need to add `'drawText' => false`

Comment: Helped in Magento 2 also :)